# Why is PyMongo literally inserting into collection?

Tags: python, pymongo

I would like the data to be inserted in mycollection, but it'll literally insert into a collection called 'collection' when I use the collection variable before insert_one.

```
client = MongoClient()
db = client['mydb']
collection = db['mycollection']
db.collection.insert_one({"id": "hello"})
```

Comment: you are not using the collection variable, you are using db.collection.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize I had to remove the db part. This worked:

```
collection = db['mycollection']
collection.insert_one({"id": "hello"})
```